# Java encoding from OS X to Windows

Tags: java, networking, encoding

I have made a primitive multi-client chat with swing GUI. Everything works fine as long as both people write from the same OS. If one of them writes from Windows and the other from OS X, the encoding of some special characters goes nuts. ( I am from CZE, we use characters as š,ě,č,ř,ž...). I have searched for a long time but didn't find anything that would help.

I have input and output defined as:

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream()));
out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(soc.getOutputStream()));
```

where soc is the socket used for connecting to the server side.

The sending process is as simple as:

```
out.println(message);
```

where message is a String, which I got from JTextArea by calling method .getText()

I know why this problem occurs, but I was unable to find any reasonable solution. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading character data from Input/OutputStreams, it's a good practice to always specify the character encoding. Otherwise the platform default encoding is used (which might not be the same on all systems).

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(soc.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(soc.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: +1 from me, but I would like to emphasize that you should use UTF-8 (as shown in example) as your standard charset.